# Number bound to function name

Tags: python

There is code:

```
def somefun():
    print "hi"
print somefun
```

Result is:

```
<function somefun at 0x0153DDF0>
```

What's 0x0153DDF0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the result of a call to `repr` - the number in question is the address of the function in memory.

According to [the doc for `repr`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#repr):

> [...] the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and **address** of the object.

(emphasis mine)

You will also find that this is the number returned by a call to `hex(id(somefun))`

**NOTE** - this being the address in memory is an **implementation detail** of CPython, and should not be relied upon.  See [the doc for `id`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) for more detail.

Comment: Note (to the OP) that this is not unique to function objects.  Even this: `class Foo(object): pass`, then `print Foo()` outputs: `<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fbc1117f610>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a function name you could use on of the following:

```
>>> print somefun.func_name
somefun
>>> print somefun.__name__ 
somefun
```